# Magento not sending emails to yahoo accounts after registeration

Tags: email, magento, gmail, yahoo

I have a problem with my magento site, I discovered it sends mails to both gmail and hotmail but not yahoo, The controller controlling the page is AccountController.php and it uses sendNewAccountEmail() function, Please I need your help in solving this problem.

this is the code that processes user registration

```
protected function _successProcessRegistration(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();
    if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
        /** @var $app Mage_Core_Model_App */
        $app = $this->_getApp();
        /** @var $store  Mage_Core_Model_Store*/
        $store = $app->getStore();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
            'confirmation',
            $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
            $store->getId()
        );
        $customerHelper = $this->_getHelper('customer');
        $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. 
        Please, check your email for the confirmation link. 
        To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.',
            $customerHelper->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));
        $url = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));
    } else {
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $session->renewSession();
        $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
    }
    $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
    return $this;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: show your code and then your question becomes clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not a code issue and is probably an email delivery issue. Are you sending these emails out via your own server? If so there may be some things you need to make sure are in place.

Check this post about Yahoo! message delivery problems, which may be related with your issue: 
http://marketingland.com/email-senders-stymied-yahoo-mail-79442